# How to work with multiple DbSets with common base class in EF 5?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 2 POCO classes:

```
class Email: Base
{
   public int SomeProperty { get; set; } 
}

class Photo: Base
{
   public int SomeOtherProperty { get; set; } 
}
```

and a base class

```
abstract class Base
{
     public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

here is my context definition:

```
public class EntitiesContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Email> Emails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
}
```

of course these classes here are just for the sake of example, things are quite more complicated.

base class is only intended to have common properties for each table - date modified, state, etc. I believe I use Table-Per-Type approach.

**PROBLEM:** I have some common business logic which I need to run against each table (for example, count non-processed items of each type). **I need a way to iterate through a set of tables with common base class.** I was hoping to do something like this:

```
private void GoThroughAllTables(Action<DbSet<Base>> fnProcess, bool needSave)
{
    using (var db = new EntitiesContext())
    {
        fnProcess(db.Emails);
        fnProcess(db.Photos);

        if (needSave == true)
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

public IEnumerable<QueueStatus> GetQueueStatus()
{
    var res = new List<QueueStatus>();

    GoThroughAllTables((set) =>
    {
        res.Add(new QueueStatus
        {
            Count = set.Cast<Base>().Count(x => x.DateCreated > someDate),
        });
    }, false);

    return res;
}

public void DeleteFailedItems()
{
    GoThroughAllTables((set) =>
    {
        set.Cast<Base>().Remove(x => x.DateCreated > someDate);
    }, true);

    return res;
}
```

this will not compile:

```
fnProcess(db.Emails);
```

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet|Email|' to
>   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet|Base|'

passing non-typed DbSet will not work because Cast will fail.

so I'm not sure what else can I try. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you not cast the `db.Emails` collection to one that contained objects of type `Base`? For that to work your `Action<DbSet<Base>>` would need to become `Action<IQueryable<Base>>`. Then you could do something like: `fnProcess(db.Emails.Select(e => (Base)e));`